# How to read PDF file from URL using Java code?

Tags: java

I want to read PDF from a URL. Then I want to check whether a particular email id is present or not using Java code.

I had tried to the following link:

http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=207&t=How_To_Read_A_PDF_File_From_A_URL_In_Java

I had attached `PDFonejava_gpl.jar` file. But I got the following error:

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

        doc.load("download.pdf");
        System.out.println("DONE.\nNumber of pages in the PDF is " +
                           doc.getPageCount());
        doc.close();
```

How can I resolve this error? or is there any other technique available to read PDF from URL?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: thank you for viewing.i got result using tika-app .